# How can I add params to a c:import tag in a loop?

Tags: java, jstl

I want to do something like this:

```
            <c:import url="${myvar.url}">
               <c:forEach items="${myvar.params}" var="param">
                  <c:param name="${param.name}" value="${param.value}"/>
               </c:forEach>
            </c:import>
```

And I get this error:

> Illegal child tag in "c:import" tag: "c:forEach" tag

Apparently, the c:import expects c:param within it and it sees a c:forEach instead.

I get the same problem if I try a jsp:include and jsp:params.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do it with either c:import or jsp:include.

If this is something you're going to do more than once, you could write a tag file, such as:

```
<%@ attribute name="url" required="true" %>
<%@ attribute name="paramMap" required="false" type="java.util.Map"%>
<%@ tag trimDirectiveWhitespaces="true"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<c:if test="${empty paramMap}">
    <c:import url="${url}"/>
</c:if>
<c:if test="${!empty paramMap}">
    <c:set var="paramString" value=""/>
    <c:forEach var="entry" items="${paramMap}">
        <c:if test="${!empty paramString}">
            <c:set var="paramString">${paramString}&</c:set>
        </c:if>
        <c:set var="paramString">${paramString}<c:out value="${entry.key}"/>=<c:out value="${entry.value}"/></c:set>
    </c:forEach>
    <c:url value="${url}?${paramString}" var="fullUrl"/>
    <c:import url="${fullUrl}"/>
</c:if>
```

Save that as "`importParamMap.tag`" in your "`WEB-INF/tags`" folder. To call it in a page, include the tags directory and treat it as any other tag:

```
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="tag" %>
...
<tag:importParamMap url="${myVar.url}" paramMap="${myVar.params}"/>
```

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to worry about messy "?" and "&" logic you could also use something like the following instead:

```
<c:url var="urlWithQueryString" value="${myvar.url}">
    <c:forEach var="thisParam" items="${myvar.params}">
        <c:param name="${thisParam.name}">${thisParam.value}</c:param>
    </c:forEach>
</c:url>

<c:import url="${urlWithQueryString}"/>
```

Comment: Note that this method also takes care of url encoding your parameters as well.

Comment: Ace! Exactly what I was looking for, and way cleaner than building the URL string with encoding etc ... Now why c:url allows for embedded logic and c:import doesn't is the big mystical question. Regardless, a great solution, many thanks.